# Loading data from SQL database into a list in C#

Tags: c#, sql

I'm working on an application that displays (highlighted) the dates on which a certain event will occur. 
In the database that I have to use there is a table that contains date intervals or collections of dates that have special meaning (like collection of holidays, school breaks...). When an event is defined, the user defines on which day(s) that event occurs (if it occurs periodically), but the user can also define that that particular event does or does not occur on special interval.
For instance - there can be an event that occurs every Sunday, if that days is not a holiday.
Now, I've solved the periodical part by reading data from the database for that event (determining on which day does that event occur) and then filling a list with dates that will be highlighted (for graphical representation I use MotnhCalendar and its BoldedDates array):

```
for (DateTime day = start; day < end;day = day.AddDays(1))
{
    if (Sunday && day.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
    {
        MarkedDates.Add(day);
    }
    monthCalendar1.BoldedDates = MarkedDates.ToArray();
}
```

Now, for this code to work properly, I need to skip the dates that belong to a special interval (in this case if that date is a holiday). It could be easily done by adding another condition into the if clause:

```
!SpecialDates.Contains(day)
```

The problem is that I don't know how to fill the list with these special dates from the database. I can't simply "hard code" it, because these special date collections/intervals can be changed at any time. So, my question is - how can I, by using SQL and C# commands, read data from database and save it in the list.

Thanks

Comment: "*how can I, by using SQL and C# commands, read data from the database and save it in the list*" - This all depends on what your using as your backend which you haven't specified.

Comment: What do you mean by backend - I'm using Visual Studio 2010, and the database is on a remote server owned by my client, and I'm not sure which SQL server are they using

Comment: By backend I mean persistence layer e.g. database. Your options will vary depending on what version of SQL server they are running, you might want to find that it out as it's kind of important.

Comment: I've contacted my client and he says that they use SQL server 2008 R2

Comment: How are you loading the data you're already loading from the database? Could you show some sample code?

Comment: Since 90% of the data is displayed in DataGridView's, I use SqlDataAdapter's to fill DataSet's or DataTable's:
`DataSet temp = new DataSet();
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Intervals ORDER BY Collection ASC";
            SDA.SelectCommand = command;
            SDA.Fill(temp);`

Comment: Try using .Net Entity Framework. It's just awesome. It reads from your database and creates an ER Model for you in Visual Studio. Then you can use that model as you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it looks like your using SQL Server 2008 R2 I would recommend using an ORM tool like [ADO.NET Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx) to access your database - best going with the latest release [EF 5](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/08/15/ef5-released.aspx).

There are tons of tutorials online on how to get up & running with it - a good one being [Creating Model Classes with the Entity Framework](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/models-%28data%29/creating-model-classes-with-the-entity-framework-cs).

To give you an idea of how simple it makes it, here is an example of the minimal amount of code you would need to achieve what it is your looking to do:

```
using (var db = new MyDbContext())
{
    var specialDates = db.SpecialDatesTable.ToList();
}
```